# Xcode - Custom template, creating groups

Tags: swift, xcode, templates

I'm trying to create group for my custom template.

[image]

I trying to do something like that:

```
> Folder
    > FileOne.swift
    > FileTwo.swift
    > FileThree.swift
```

Actually my template look like:

```
> FileOne.swift
> FileTwo.swift
> FileThree.swift
```

What I currently tried with `nodes` and `definitions`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kind</key>
    <string>Xcode.IDEKit.TextSubstitutionFileTemplateKind</string>
    <key>Platforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
    </array>
    <key>Options</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Nodes</key>
            <array>
                <string>___FILEBASENAME___/___FILEBASENAME___Coordinator.swift</string>
            </array>
            <key>Definitions</key>
            <dict>
                <key>___FILEBASENAME___/___FILEBASENAME___Coordinator.swift</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Group</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>___FILEBASENAME___</string>
                            </array>
                            <key>Path</key>
                            <string>___FILEBASENAME___Coordinator.swift</string>
                        </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>productName</string>
            <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Module Name</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>MVVM-C RxSwift UIKit</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
            <key>Default</key>
            <string>Module1</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```